# Cyclic dependency in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse

I know this matter doesn't get enough attention because it's not meet often but I want to clarify it.

Say I have 3 files:

A.h

```
#ifndef A_h
#define A_h
#include "B.h"
class A {
    A();
    virtual ~A();
    bool someFunc(B& b);
};
#endif
```

B.h

```
#ifndef B_h
#define B_h
#include "A.h"
class B {
    B();
    virtual ~B();
    bool someFunc(A& a);
};
#endif
```

and main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
int main() { return 0; }
```

without the protection (#ifndef X_h #define X_h) there is a Cyclic dependency. Adding the protection should solve the problem but when the code is compiled first main.cpp tries to include a.h which tries to include b.h before a is declared and that returns an error. If we change the code to:

A.h

```
#ifndef A_h
#define A_h
class A {
    A();
    virtual ~A();
#include "B.h"
    bool someFunc(B& b);
};
#endif
```

B.h

```
#ifndef B_h
#define B_h
class B {
    B();
    virtual ~B();
#include "A.h"
    bool someFunc(A& a);
};
#endif
```

Now the Cyclic dependency is solved but and the code compiles without error but still Eclipse returns an error: "Type 'B' could not be resolved" in A.h so you need to add surpress to both A.h and B.h where the other one is used. I want to know if there is another way to solve the Cyclic dependency without Eclipse returning an error and how should the code look if we have more than two classes (A includes B, C and D; B includes A, C, D ...)

Comment: Forward declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't actually use *instance* of class `B` in class `A` and the other way around, and only declare functions taking pointers or references, you can get away without including at all, and only *declare* the classes:

In file A.h

```
#ifndef A_h
#define A_h

class B;  // Declare class B

class A {
    A();
    virtual ~A();
    bool someFunc(B& b);
};
#endif
```

and in B.h

```
#ifndef B_h
#define B_h

class A;  //Declare class A

class B {
    B();
    virtual ~B();
    bool someFunc(A& a);
};
#endif
```

In the source files where the functions are defined (implemented) you of course needs to include both files.

Comment: Even `bool someFunc(class B& b);` will work, i.e. "local" forward declaration.